Which "other travel websites" does Booking.com fetch reviews from?
Booking.com says that for listings that do not have reviews yet, they will fetch reviews from "other travel websites" but they do not mention which ones.

Which websites are they talking about? The reason I am curious is because on the listing in the screenshot they say they have 23 guest reviews from other websites, however, when I tried finding the listing on other websites I could find no other ones, except for booking.com itself.
So I am wondering where they got the reviews from, and whether they can be trusted. I am hesitant to just take booking.com at their word that they come from a trustworthy source (not saying they are not, but it would be nice to. know where they came from.)

Have you checked for the property on AirBnb?

Did booking.com state anywhere that the reviews come from a trustworthy source? As far as I can see they just state that it is from 'other travel websites'.

@quarague "These reviews are imported from third-party travel websites that we trust and have similar standards to our platform. We review all external review scores every few weeks to make sure they’re accurate and up-to-date."

No idea if this is true/up to date, but in their support pages for partners (hosts), they state:

External review scores
You’ll be able to import external reviews by providing your property’s link from other channels during registration. This won’t be possible after registration is complete. Currently, our platform can only import reviews from AirBnB.
(…)

So the “several other websites” would be only AirBnb.
